# Scraping the same page forever using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Doing **scraping**. How can I stay on a page and read the content to search for data every xx seconds without refresh the page? I use this way but the pc crashes after some time. Any ideas on how to make it efficient? I would like to achieve it without using while (true). The readOdds function does not always delay the same time.

```
//...
while(true){
   const html = await page.content();
   cant = await readOdds(html); // some code with the html
   console.info('Waiting 5 seconds to read again...');
   await page.waitFor(5000);
}
```

this is a section

```
async function readOdds(htmlPage){
    try {
        var savedat = functions.mysqlDateTime(new Date());
        var pageHtml=htmlPage.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        var exp_text_all = /<coupon-section(.*?)<\/coupon-section>/g;
        var leagueLinksMatches = pageHtml.match(exp_text_all);
        var cmarkets = 0;

        let reset = await mysqlfunctions.promise_updateMarketsCount(cmarkets, table_markets_count, site);
        console.log(reset);

        if(leagueLinksMatches == null){
            return cmarkets;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < leagueLinksMatches.length; i++) {
            const html = leagueLinksMatches[i];
            var expc = /class="title ellipsis-text">(.*?)<\/span/g;
            var nameChampionship = functions.getDataInHtmlCode(String(html).match(expc)[0]);

            var idChampionship = await mysqlfunctions.promise_db_insert_Championship(nameChampionship, gsport, table_championship);
           

            var exp_text = /<ui-event-line(.*?)<\/ui-event-line>/g;
            var text = html.match(exp_text);
            // console.info(text.length);

            for (let index = 0; index < text.length; index++) {
                const element = text[index];               
....
```

Comment: Introduce a [process manager](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) which will spawn the process (your node app) when it comes down.

Comment: ok great, I will install it via npm to test and see the logs. Thank you.

Comment: I can tell your code (or dependencies) leaks memory, without seeing the logs.

Comment: Yes, I think that even the micro can overheat and that's why the PC is turned off. Once the script is running I can not connect via ehorus, which is how I do it on the pc I'm testing. I thought to use setInterval, but the problem with that solution is that I must give a maximum time to ensure that it never fails, and there are times when data reading is done in a couple of seconds, other times 20 or more, the time lost is important for this software that I am implementing.

Comment: Show us the readOdds function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Simple Solution with recursive callback

However before we go into that, you can try to run the function itself instead of `while` which will loop forever without any proper control.

```
const readLoop = async() => {
  const html = await page.content();
  cant = await readOdds(html);
  return readLoop() // run the loop again
}

// invoke it for infinite callbacks without any delays at all
await readLoop();
```

Which will run the same block function continuously, without any delay, as long as your readOdds function returns. You won't have to use `page.waitFor` and `while`.

## Memory leak prevention

For advanced cases where you have respawn over a period of time, Queue like [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) and process manager like [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) comes into play. However, queue will void your `without refresh the page?` part of your question.

You definitely should use pm2 though.

The usage is as follows,

```
npm i -g pm2
pm2 start index.js --name=myawesomeapp // or your app file
```

There are few useful arguments,

- `--max-memory-restart 100M`, It can limit memory usage to 100M and restart itself.
- `--max-restarts 50`, It will stop working once it restarts 50 times due to error (or memory leak).

You can check the logs using `pm2 logs myawesomeapp` as you set the name above.

Comment: I managed to improve the use of resources a bit by using sleep function(internally setTimeOut)  instead of page.waitFor, but your solution seems better to me. Thank you.

Comment: My first answer was with setTimeout and setInterval, however those have similar side effects to your while loop. :) You are welcome.